# FatalAppExitA just shows only a = char

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I'm just testing `FatalAppExitA` on VB.net, but for some reason it just displays me a equals character. I will use this function on some of my future apps, but I need to know what is happening here.

Here is a screenshot of the message box:

[image: screenshot]

And here is the code:

```
Private Declare Sub FatalAppExit Lib "kernel32" Alias "FatalAppExitA" (
    ByVal uAction As Long,
    ByVal lpMessageText As String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FatalAppExit(0&, "FatalAppExit Test")
End Sub
Private Declare Sub FatalExit Lib "kernel32" (ByVal code As Long)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `As Long` is vb6/vba syntax, in vb.net you must declare the parameter `As Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question `vb.net`, so let's use the VB.Net syntax for the function declaration.

Given the [FatalAppExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-fatalappexitw) definition:

```
void FatalAppExitW(
  UINT    uAction,
  LPCWSTR lpMessageText
);
```

This can be declared as:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Friend Shared Sub FatalAppExit(uAction As UInteger, lpMessageText As String)
End Sub
```

You could also specify `CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi` or `CharSet:=CharSet.Auto`, won't change the result, the string is marshaled correctly in any case.

As noted, `uAction As Long` is uncalled for, the C++ declaration defines an `UINT` Type parameter, so let's use the corresponding `UInteger` Type.

Then call it as:

```
FatalAppExit(0, "FatalAppExit Test")
```

You may also be interested in:

[Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)
[Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api)
[Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes)